# Why im getting single verts when separate selected

Tags: modifiers

With the array modifier i created 12 mesh and applied the modifier. And now i want to separate them to make them 12 mesh. But it creates a single verts only. Is there any other way or whats going wrong why i cannot create 12 mesh from it by the selection option

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why use the array modifier? Could create copy and distribute [example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58187/how-can-i-arrange-items-in-a-circle-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

You've applied the modifier, so now you have one object, and inside this object you have several meshes that compose your different small cabins.

If each of your cabin is made of one mesh, in *Edit* mode, select all and separate with <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts* and you will have 12 different objects.

If each of your cabin is made of several meshes,  in *Edit* mode, select each object and <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*.

Comment: Lose parts not give me 12 objects. its giving me 119 mesh.

Comment: because each object is made of different meshes, so in your case the solution is to select each object and to make a P > Selection. But why did you use array? we gave you solutions without array, once you apply the array I don't think you have any other solution than separate